# android better save image option?

Tags: java, android

Currently I am using the compress method to save an image taken with the camera hardware on the android phone to the SD card.

```
try {
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 10;
Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
imageData.length,options);

fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/"+fileName+".png");

BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
fileOutputStream); 
myImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

Now this works perfectly fine, however, the quality of image it saves hardly makes it worth taking the picture in the first place. I'm looking for a better way to save the picture at a higher quality.

Comment: are you sure  the original pic has   good quality?

Comment: save it as PNG.. You are compressing the image to full capacity.. ie 100%.. try lesser value..

Comment: @blackbelt: The app is taking a picture with the camera hardware on the droid phone. So yes the original picture has good quality.

Comment: @userSeven7s: Negative. Changing it to a lower number did not affect the quality in a good way, in fact it made it worse.

Comment: @userSeven7s  100 meaning compress for max quality, take a look to the doc

Comment: @JoshuaRedfield do you perform any kind of processing on the image?

Comment: @blackbelt exactly why I had it at 100 in the first place. My app is a simple camera APP. It uses the hardware camera to take a picture and then save it to the SD card. However, the quality even at 100 is so low it hardly makes it worth taking the picture to begin with. And yes, My camera is fine as other camera apps take high quality pictures.

Comment: @blackbelt I'll edit my original posting and upload the full snippet of code I am using.

Comment: @JoshuaRedfield Sorry I mistook it for compression ratio..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
options.inSampleSize = 10;
```

here is your loss of quality: This will create an image of 1/10 in `heigth` and `width`

From the doc:

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is
>   the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single
>   pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an
>   image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the
>   number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the
>   decoder will try to fulfill this request, but the resulting bitmap may
>   have different dimensions that precisely what has been requested.
>   Also, powers of 2 are often faster/easier for the decoder to honor.

Comment: Thanks. Fresh set of eyes helps, I guess I misunderstood what exactly inSampleSize was doing. Thought like the compress quality higher number was better.. but I as wrong :P